# Problems adding rpm repository

Tags: rpm

I'm trying to add repoforge repo to a Centos 6 x86_64 box to install collectd 5.1. Package is listed here: http://pkgs.repoforge.org/collectd/

I've added rpm with:
`rpm -ivh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm`, done `yum clean all`, but `yum --showduplicates list collectd` doesn't show version 5. `yum search collectd-dbi` (is also listed on the first link) doesn't return any results either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use repository rpmforge-testing

yum search collectd-dbi --enablerepo=rpmforge-testing